# Почему нет интернета при включенном OpenVPN?

Tags: ip, vpn, openvpn

Настроил OpenVPN как в [этом видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLJWPLSRwdg). Также на сервере прописал `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` для смены ip-адреса в клиенте на сервер, но ничего не выходит...

Если конкретней, то у меня на клиенте просто пропал интернет и всё. Как можно это исправить?

Сервер:

```
dev-node "ServerVPN"
mode server
port 12345 

proto tcp4-server
dev tun

tls-server
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ta.key" 0

tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh2048.pem"

server 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0

client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config"

verb 3

route-delay 5
route-method exe

push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
route 192.168.182.0 255.255.255.0
```

Клиент:

```
remote 192.168.1.1 ip для примера
client
port 12345

proto tcp4-client
dev tun

tls-client
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server

tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ClientVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ClientVPN.key"

cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

verb 3
mute 20
```

### ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ

Route print:

После подключения:

```
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
15...00 ff cb c6 07 3a ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
14...d8 f2 ca c4 2e 9a ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
2...da f2 ca c4 2e 99 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
10...d8 f2 ca c4 2e 99 ......Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
18...d8 f2 ca c4 2e 9d ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес Маска сети Адрес шлюза Интерфейс Метрика
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.122 35
0.0.0.0 128.0.0.0 10.10.10.5 10.10.10.6 281
10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.5 10.10.10.6 281
10.10.10.4 255.255.255.252 On-link 10.10.10.6 281
10.10.10.6 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.10.10.6 281
10.10.10.7 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.10.10.6 281
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
127.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
128.0.0.0 128.0.0.0 10.10.10.5 10.10.10.6 281
178.44.196.105 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.122 291
192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.5 10.10.10.6 281
192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
192.168.1.122 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
192.168.1.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 10.10.10.6 281
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.10.10.6 281
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
Отсутствует

IPv6 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Метрика Сетевой адрес Шлюз
1 331 ::1/128 On-link
15 281 fe80::/64 On-link
10 291 fe80::/64 On-link
15 281 fe80::5105:7c9d:a5c0:c8dc/128
On-link
10 291 fe80::e1e3:a6c6:ab15:60c8/128
On-link
1 331 ff00::/8 On-link
15 281 ff00::/8 On-link
10 291 ff00::/8 On-link
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
Отсутствует
```

До подключения:

```
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
15...00 ff cb c6 07 3a ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
14...d8 f2 ca c4 2e 9a ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
2...da f2 ca c4 2e 99 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
10...d8 f2 ca c4 2e 99 ......Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
18...d8 f2 ca c4 2e 9d ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес Маска сети Адрес шлюза Интерфейс Метрика
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.122 35
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
127.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
192.168.1.122 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
192.168.1.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 331
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 192.168.1.122 291
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
Отсутствует

IPv6 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Метрика Сетевой адрес Шлюз
1 331 ::1/128 On-link
10 291 fe80::/64 On-link
10 291 fe80::e1e3:a6c6:ab15:60c8/128
On-link
1 331 ff00::/8 On-link
10 291 ff00::/8 On-link
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
Отсутствует
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что при установлении связи формируется маршрут по умолчанию через установленное соединение, причём метрика получается меньше, и все пакеты идут туда. Или существующий дефолтный гейт попадает в подсеть поднятого канала. Если так (покажите ROUTE PRINT до и после поднятия канала), то надо настроить так, чтобы OpenVPN передавал только маршрут в нужную подсеть, а не дефолтный (либо после поднятия канала удалить дефолтные маршруты и заново ввести только правильный).

Comment: @Akina, обновил вопрос

Comment: Ну, как видите, OpenVPN добавляет кучу своих маршрутов. Маршрут `128.0.0.0 128.0.0.0 10.10.10.5 10.10.10.6 281` собственно и заворачивает половину пакетов куда не надо (проверьте - после поднятия канала Вы должны по-прежнему нормально пинговать гугловский DNS 8.8.8.8, но не ru.stackoverflow.com, которые все в 151.101/16).

Comment: @Akina, при подключенном OpenVPN он даже 8.8.8.8 не пингует -_-

Как это решается?

Comment: *при подключенном OpenVPN он даже 8.8.8.8 не пингует* Не пингуется - это ниачём. Что именно - timeout? no route to host?  что-то ещё? Попробуйте `tracert 8.8.8.8` без VPN и с ним. И смотрите, в чём разница.

Comment: @Akina, привышен интервал ожидания запроса

Comment: @Akina, с VPN привышен интервал ожидания запроса уже на первой строке, а без него +- на 10 выходит

Comment: Timeout означает, что компьютер предполагает, что знает, куда посылать пакет, успешно отправляет его, но не получает ответа. То, что это происходит сразу, на первом хопе, говорит о том, что VPN не принимает его, молча отправляя в мусор. В качестве эксперимента попробуйте удалить роуты в 0,0,0,0 и 128,0,0,0, а потом заново создать корректный  маршрут в 0/0.

Comment: @Akina, не помогло...

Comment: Ну тогда остаётся только вдумчиво читать маны на openvpn и смотреть типовые конфигурации и решения для него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решалась настройкой маршрутизации в роутере и редактированием его конфигурационного файла

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/624327)

Comment: @Spatz, я и есть автор XD Просто для каждого роутера это всё надо отдельно прописывать, да и врядли кто-то незнающий и не шарящий в этом захочет также позаниматься жарко кхм-кхм. Поэтому я просто пометил, что ответ был найден, помощь больше не нужна)